# Convergence of integral to convergence a.e question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

OK, so now I have $$\int_0^T{\phi(t)h_n(t)} \to \int_0^T{\phi(t)h(t)}$$ which holds for all $\phi \in C^\infty_c(0,T).$ From this how can I deduce that $h_n \to h$ (a.e)?

I think I need maybe something to do with Fatou but I am not sure.

($h_n = \frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega(t)}{f_ng}$, and $h$ is similar but without the $n$. Also I know that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^2(O,T;L^2(\Omega(t))$.)

Comment: You should provide some assumption on the sequence $\{h_n\}_n$.

Comment: @Siminore All I know is that $f_n$ is bounded uniformly in the $H^1([0,T]\times \Omega(t))$ norm.